# l3fp "Number too big" error

Tags: errors, l3fp

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\SideLength[1]{\calc{sqrt(#1)}}
\newcommand*\Angle[1]{\calc{asin(1/sqrt(#1))}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2.9,-3.5)(4.5,2.2)
  \multido{\iA = 2+1, \iB = 1+1}{16}{%
    \psRelLine[angle = \Angle{\iA}](0,0)(2,0){\SideLength{\iB}}{A}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

When compiling, I get the error

```
! Number too big.
<argument> 7853981633
                     974483
l.17 ...ngle{\iA}](0,0)(2,0){\SideLength{\iB}}{A}}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the full set of digits from `l3fp` back to `pstricks`, but that's too many! (The LaTeX3 FPU is IEEE-compliant so works at 16 digit precision.) In common with many TeX packages, `pstricks` is expecting a number here with no more digits than TeX will accept as a `\number`. Probably the easiest fix is to round within the FPU:

```
\newcommand*\Angle[1]{\calc{round(asin(1/sqrt(#1)),5)}}
```

or

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new:Npn \calc #1 { \fp_eval:n { round ( #1 , 5 ) } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

depending on your use cases. (Five decimal digits is probably enough to pass back to most TeX end-uses.)

Comment: "5 digits should be enough for anyone."  You may live to rue those words!

Comment: @AndrewStacey I did say 'probably' :-) Depending on the internal set up of what you send data back to, you may loose additional places in any case. (Picking up as a dimen is not uncommon, and that limits you to 5 d.p.)