# Error: "! Number too big.<argument> 10000000149011612"

Tags: errors, pstricks

I am doing this code but there is an error. Could you please show me how to fix it? Thank you so much for your help.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\newrgbcolor{qqwuqq}{0. 0.39215686274509803 0.}
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=4pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-3.7568904786615005,-4.384766822441855)(3.8745897756640084,4.522639152638371)
\pscircle[linewidth=1.2pt](-1.,1.){0.6013318551349164}
\pscircle[linewidth=1.2pt](1.,-1.){0.6}
\pscircle[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=blue](0.,-2.6){0.6}
\pscircle[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=blue](0.,2.6){0.6013318551349164}
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2.,3.6)(2.,3.6)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2.,3.6)(-2.,-3.6)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2.,-3.6)(2.,-3.6)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](2.,-3.6)(2.,3.6)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](1.4,1.2)(0.41471162423097696,2.1645527945574745)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](1.4,1.2)(-1.4,-1.2)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](-1.4,-1.2)(-0.4331929230692547,-2.184856782058631)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=red]{->}(0.7019440055958751,2.312523331001718)(1.101944005595875,1.912523331001718)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=red]{->}(0.6,0.14)(-0.18,-0.52)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=red]{->}(-1.1576038046165968,-1.9232466978315976)(-0.7376038046165968,-2.3232466978315975)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt]{->}(0.,2.594397934973955)(1.1870980815350114,2.5790371632198057)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt]{->}(0.41471162423097696,2.1645527945574745)(-0.7790807029960851,3.3777972944355596)
\pscustom[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=qqwuqq,fillcolor=qqwuqq,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.10000000149011612]{
\parametricplot{-0.012939044174906414}{2.3481132888648557}{0.7222221060875875*cos(t)+0.|0.7222221060875875*sin(t)+2.594397934973955}
\lineto(0.,2.594397934973955)\closepath}
\pscircle[linewidth=1.2pt,linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt,linecolor=blue](1.4,1.2){0.6001921863196109}
\pscircle[linewidth=1.2pt,linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt,linecolor=blue](-1.4,-1.2){0.6000009998169441}
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt]{->}(-0.005894842078381424,2.592012806005451)(-0.7606621598810974,3.3590786315489147)
\begin{scriptsize}
\rput[bl](1.5394049659808087,-3.060692961281281){\blue{$T$}}
\rput[bl](1.057923561922417,2.331898764172694){\red{$f_1$}}
\rput[bl](0.33570145583482935,-0.43661930916305214){\red{$f_2$}}
\rput[bl](-1.277261247760783,-2.4588412062082927){\red{$f_3$}}
\psdots[dotstyle=*](-1.,1.)
\rput[bl](-1.5902241603987377,0.9596767626062807){$x_2$}
\psdots[dotstyle=*](1.,-1.)
\rput[bl](1.3227383341545325,-1.0384710642360404){$x_3$}
\rput[bl](0.02273854319687472,2.9096764490427627){\qqwuqq{$\alpha_1$}}
\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](1.4,1.2)
\rput[bl](1.7801456680100045,1.1041211838237979){\darkgray{$x_5$}}
\psdots[dotstyle=*](-0.005894842078381424,2.592012806005451)
\rput[bl](-0.6031872820790345,2.4041209747814527){$x_1$}
\psdots[dotstyle=*](0.,-2.587616640264122)
\rput[bl](-0.579113211876115,-2.6755078380345685){$x_4$}
\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](-1.4,-1.2)
\rput[bl](-1.9994833538483705,-1.3273599066710748){\darkgray{$x_7$}}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

The error is
"! Number too big. 10000000149011612 \lineto(0.,2.594397934973955)\closepath}"

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) that value only seems to be in the opacity arg to pscustom, are you sure it have the correct value? Not at pc so cannot test.

Comment: By the way, what do you hope to achieve by specifying numbers with 15 and more digits of precision?

Comment: @Daleif  I think so. Honestly, I used Geogebra to transfer a picture to this code. But when I was running the code, the error appeared. I tried with another picture and it works really good, so I don't know why I can not proceed it with this picture. Btw, I read a link related to this error https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155104/l3fp-number-too-big-error?rq=1

Comment: @Mico I don't really need to use the specific numbers like that. Thanks Mico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The export of GeoGebra is a mess. At least use `\lineto(0,2.594)` because PostScript cannot handle so many decimals. All other values are ok but without any sense.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\newrgbcolor{qqwuqq}{0. 0.3921 0.}
\psset{algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=4pt 
    0,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25,linewidth=1.2pt}
\begin{pspicture*}(-3.756,-4.384)(3.8745,4.5226)
\pscircle(-1.,1.){0.6013318551349164}
\pscircle(1.,-1.){0.6}
\pscircle[linecolor=blue](0.,-2.6){0.6}
\pscircle[linecolor=blue](0.,2.6){0.6013318551349164}
\pspolygon(-2.,-3.6)(-2.,3.6)(2.,3.6)(2,-3.6)
\psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](1.4,1.2)(0.41,2.164)
\psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](1.4,1.2)(-1.4,-1.2)
\psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 
    2pt](-1.4,-1.2)(-0.433,-2.184)
\psline[linecolor=red]{->}(0.7019,2.3125)(1.10194,1.912)
\psline[linecolor=red]{->}(0.6,0.14)(-0.18,-0.52)
\psline[linecolor=red]{->}(-1.157,-1.923)(-0.7376,-2.323)
\psline{->}(0.,2.594)(1.1870,2.5790)
\psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt]{->}(0.4147,2.164)(-0.7790,3.3777)
\pscustom[linecolor=qqwuqq,fillcolor=qqwuqq,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.1]{%
  \parametricplot{-0.01293}{2.34811}{0.7222*cos(t)|0.7222*sin(t)+2.594397}
  \lineto(0,2.59439)
\closepath}
\pscircle[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt,linecolor=blue](1.4,1.2){0.6001}
\pscircle[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt,linecolor=blue](-1.4,-1.2){0.60}
\psline{->}(-0.0058,2.592)(-0.7606,3.3590)
\scriptsize
\rput[bl](1.53940,-3.0606){\blue{$T$}}
\rput[bl](1.0579,2.331){\red{$f_1$}}
\rput[bl](0.3357,-0.4366){\red{$f_2$}}
\rput[bl](-1.277,-2.4588){\red{$f_3$}}
\psdots[dotstyle=*](-1.,1.)
\rput[bl](-1.5902,0.9596){$x_2$}
\psdots[dotstyle=*](1.,-1.)
\rput[bl](1.322,-1.0384){$x_3$}
\rput[bl](0.0227,2.909676){\qqwuqq{$\alpha_1$}}
\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](1.4,1.2)
\rput[bl](1.78014,1.10412){\darkgray{$x_5$}}
\psdots[dotstyle=*](-0.0058,2.5920)
\rput[bl](-0.6031,2.4041){$x_1$}
\psdots[dotstyle=*](0.,-2.58761)
\rput[bl](-0.5791,-2.67550){$x_4$}
\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](-1.4,-1.2)
\rput[bl](-1.9994,-1.3273){\darkgray{$x_7$}}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]